# validar con javascript si se ingreso un correo o no

Tags: javascript

Cómo puedo validar si se ingresó un email o no, ya que el input type email no me valida nada

```html
<input class="email" type="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico">

<button class="button">Validar</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas escuchar el evento del botón y tomar el valor del input para validarlo. La validación se puede hacer con una `Regular expression`:

```js
var re = new RegExp(/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/)

var boton = document.querySelector('#validar')

boton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var email = document.querySelector('input').value
  if (!email.match(re)){
    console.log('correo invalido')
  } else {
    console.log('correo valido')
  }
    
})
```

```html
<input type="email" name="email">
<button id="validar">Validar</button>
```